# How to create and pass variables through LLDB's python scripting

Tags: python, debugging, lldb

I'm running a python script through LLDB to provide some more information that assists internal developers when debugging.

As part of this, I have a need to create a variable and pass it to a function - luckily they're not standard variables and therefore it shouldn't have any name mangling issues.

I can create a variable easily like so:

`newVar = valobj.EvaluateExpression('cppDatatype("Hello World!")')`

And get its name via `strx.GetName()` which for example, can be `$1`

Successively, I'm trying to call a function on the valobj and pass my aforementioned `$1` like so:

`usefulInfo = valobj.EvaluateExpression('getUsefulInfo({})'.format(newVar.GetName()))`

For the rest I was planning to get the data from `usefulInfo`, but unfortunately I'm getting lldb's "unknown error" when trying to call `getUsefulInfo` and pass the name of the newly created variable.

Surely I must be doing this wrong, what would be the correct way to call an object's function, pass a freshly created variable in LLDB python script to it and receive a new variable back so that you can read its data later via `GetData`?

Comment: That should work, I tried the same thing with a trivial example and it did.  We'll need more particulars - maybe even a simple example that is failing - to help figure out why this isn't working in your instance.

Comment: Note that the $0, $1, etc. are effectively like "const" variables, their role is to capture the value at the time the expression was run, then not change so you can use them as historical values.  You can also make more normal "user variables" in the lldb expression parser by running expressions like: `int $my_int = 10`.  That one you can assign new values to, etc.  I don't think that's what is causing your issue.  But this might be a more convenient way to get temp variables for the expression parser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jim Ingham whose comments ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73501037/how-to-create-and-pass-variables-through-lldbs-python-scripting/74107656#comment129804962_73501037), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73501037/how-to-create-and-pass-variables-through-lldbs-python-scripting/74107656#comment129805026_73501037)):

> That should work, I tried the same thing with a trivial example and it did. We'll need more particulars - maybe even a simple example that is failing - to help figure out why this isn't working in your instance.

and

> Note that the $0, $1, etc. are effectively like "const" variables, their role is to capture the value at the time the expression was run, then not change so you can use them as historical values. You can also make more normal "user variables" in the lldb expression parser by running expressions like: `int $my_int = 10`. That one you can assign new values to, etc. I don't think that's what is causing your issue. But this might be a more convenient way to get temp variables for the expression parser.

provided the answer.

When trying using trivial data types it works very well, so I decided to go ahead and implement some functions to bring down the more complex `cppDatatype` to C strings which I can read from the python side without problems!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32969906)